# Como diminuir este código em PHP?

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um código em PHP que formate o tempo que o site busca no banco de dados. É bem simples. Queria saber se tem como diminui-lo. Segue abaixo o código:

```
$tempo = new DateTime($abre);
$abre = $tempo -> format('H:i');
$tempo = new DateTime($fecha);
$fecha = $tempo -> format('H:i');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode fazer assim, ao adicionar parenteses ao criar o objeto já pode chamar algum método do classe.

```
$abre = (new DateTime($abre))->format('H:i');
$fecha = (new DateTime($fecha))->format('H:i');
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!